# Data migration excel to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am importing data from an excel spread sheet into Microsoft SQL Server 2008. One of the columns in my excel sheet is a "songs" column that contains a list of songs separated by commas and there are a different number of songs in each row. How do I write a function that can split up the songs and put them into a table in SQL?

Comment: First thing first get your data into a staging table in sql server, Than google Sql Server `Split Function` and from that use that split function and populate your data into your actual destination table.

Comment: I hope to be right, but I think you can pull up information using **SSIS**, and specify the delimitation there

Comment: what did you try to do?